# How to find delete command executed for a specific schema in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Can some 1 help me if there is a way in red shift form  which I can get the history of delete commands which was being executed on a specific schema
I have tried looking into queries  tab in red shift cluster and also traversed stl_delete table but no luck,

I wish to know the query ,time of executed ,user and date  on which it was executed

Is there any other way i can validate if any delete command were being executed for that specific schema in redshift

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select userid, starttime, endtime, querytxt 
from stl_query
where querytxt like 'delete %from <schema_name>.%'
```

See [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_QUERY.html).